# Cross platform app in Windows 7 using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, xamarin-studio

**Goal: to develop cross platform app for Android, Windows and iOS.**

I have Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 7 including the Xamarin platform.

Problem is that when I create a new project with a blank app (Xamarin.forms portable), it doesn't create project for Windows phone. And when I create blank app (Xamarin.forms shared), it throws the following error:

```
This computer must be upgraded to windows 8.1 to load this project.
```

What do I have to do to create a cross platform app (that works on Android, iOS, Windows Phone) using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Btw why is this tagged with XamarinStudio when you are using VisualStudio?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error for Windows Phone project because Visual Studio(not Xamarin) doesn't support WP8/8.1 development on Windows 7 out of the box. Google "WP8 SDK on Windows 7".

Comment: I noticed that there are workaround for install sdk 8.0 in windows 7 but can't find one for sdk 8.1. Are the steps similiar?

Answer (score 0):

WP 8.1 SDK is required window 8.1 or later. Then the best solution is upgrade your OS to Window 8.1